# Able to access the content on scrolling down the PopUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am showing a div as a pop up. Right now the issue is pop up is centered but if i scroll down i am able to click on the content of my application in which it should not happen when the pop up is appeared.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(showPopup(), 5000);
});
function showPopup() {
    $('#userId').show(0, function () {
         $('#userid').css('z-index','5');
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        $('.popUp').center();
    });
}
```

So i am looking it to make it like to move the div popup up and down position centered if the user scrolls up and down. Please help . Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid background content click, you can create a overlay at the runtime dynamically using jquery inside body like this:

```
function showPopup() {
   $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    $('#userId').show(0, function () {
         $('#userid').css('z-index','5');
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        $('.popUp').center();
    });
}
```

`CSS` properties for overlay

```
.overlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; background:transparent; z-index:2;}
```

Just make sure to remove this overlay using `$('.overlay').remove()` when you are closing your popup

Comment: This is what exactly i am looking for. Can i ask for a small favour?? Is there a way i can make the background of the pop up transparent ?

Comment: @step yes you can, as i am not confirm about your popup html so i am assuming `.popup` as your main popup class. So you can use `$('.popup').css('background', 'transparent')`. But i am wondering why do you want to make your popup background as transparent?

Comment: Hey @step, also you can upvote this answer so that it helps others. Thanks

Comment: i have tried to do that but i dont have enough points to do that. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark as I don't know the markup. But looking at your code you are probably going to need something like this:

```
function showPopup() {
  $('#userId').show(0, function () {
    $('#userid').css('z-index','5')
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto')
    $('.popUp').center().css('position', 'fixed') /* line changed */
  });
}
```

It will set the css position property on the popup to 'fixed', which should keep it suspended in place, even when scrolling.

Comment: This makes pop up centered even if i move up and down which is good. But  once i scroll down i am able click on the content even if the pop up is open. @shennan

Comment: @step Add an overlay inside or below the popup to stop things being clicked below.

Answer (score 0):

You just put your popup into a wrapper container, which has `fixed` position and stretch full width & height of the viewport.

```css
p {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.popup {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 25%; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* width: 300px; */
    /* margin-left: -150px; */
    top: 50%; /* added */
    left: 50%; /* added */
    margin-right: -50%; /* added */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* added */
    padding: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Neque a enim veniam. Ullam magni excepturi a mollitia vero suscipit sapiente, eos odit deserunt possimus aut itaque explicabo aliquam labore qui.</p>
<p>Omnis quos cupiditate deserunt animi asperiores corrupti facere assumenda fugiat tenetur voluptatem hic inventore neque iure amet, iste dignissimos vel placeat, nulla.</p>
<p>Reiciendis, cupiditate numquam ducimus, vel optio aliquid obcaecati atque cumque praesentium expedita quos illum dignissimos rem distinctio aliquam modi voluptas harum repellat.</p>
<p>Beatae eveniet porro, soluta consequatur quasi. Tempore dignissimos delectus exercitationem quos, possimus labore alias quisquam fuga vero. Ex illum dolores asperiores amet.</p>
<p>Atque, unde harum consectetur id delectus eligendi, incidunt similique nostrum! Fugiat tenetur iusto, ab ipsum explicabo tempora voluptatibus eum sunt error repellendus.</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="popup">
    Your popup content goes here..
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks cool. But what if i have additional divs down to that? like 

<div class="container">
  <div class="popup">
    Your popup content goes here..
  </div>
</div>
<div>something else</div> . Then the Something else will be down to the transparent portion right? @Pig Ball

Comment: @step It depend on where you place your `something else` div and your CSS. The code snippet abow just an example.

Comment: Actually thats exactly what i am looking for. I have tried this but i see some flaws..Can you plese let me know hoe can i over come those?
if i resize the window the pop is not fully visible.It stays where it is even if i resize the window. how can make it center based on the window size and make it scrollable aloong with the background?

Comment: I updated the code snippet to keep the popup always centered at any sizes. You can visit [Center things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) for more example about centering things in css.